# iframe height 150px but div container is larger

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am having a very weird problem, and I guess it means there is something I don't understand enough.

I am simplifying the example so as to make it easy to find the problem, but actually this is part of a very large website.

The outer `<div>` has an absolute position which is 10px from the top and bottom. To my understanding that means that it has an exact height (the screen - 20px).

Inside I have another `<div>` which has a height of `auto`, and in that an `<iframe>` with 100% height.

My reasoning is that it should give me the entire height of the page for the iframe.

But for some reason, in chrome the iframe has a max-height of 150px no matter what height or max-height I give the iframe.

To make things weirder, in IE it works as I expected.

I inspected the chrome devtools, and it shows 150px with no source.

Searching over SO shows me lots of similar questions, but no satisfying answer, since I set the outer div size.

Any suggestions how to fix this?

```css
.body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.inner {
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="inner">
    <iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net" style="height:100%">
    
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, a height in percent always needs a height on the parent element, auto won't work.

Comment: if you change your .inner height to 100% i think it gives you what you are looking for

Comment: @CBroe even if the parents parent has a fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[HEIGHT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)**

> Percentages   The percentage is calculated with respect to the height of
>   the generated box's containing block. If the height of the containing
>   block is not specified explicitly (i.e., it depends on content
>   height), and this element is not absolutely positioned, the value
>   computes to auto. A percentage height on the root element is relative
>   to the initial containing block.

```css
.body {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.inner {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="inner">
    <iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net" style="height:100%">
    
    </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```